# EditText inside a dialog returns null

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog

I have a button inside `MainActivity` which on clicking shows up a `dialog` which conatins an `EditText` and a `Button`. I want to display the `EditText` as a `Toast` message but the whatever input the `EditText` receives, it returns `null`

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.hp.sample13.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Show"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
String str;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            dialog.show();
            EditText edit=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            str=edit.getText().toString();
            Button button1=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"String : "+str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

}

The problem here is that the `Toast` message displayed on the screen is `String :`. It does not print whatever we input in the `EditText`.

**custom_dialog**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Enter your new password"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Modify"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can you please help. Thank you :)

Comment: Returns `"null"`, or *throws an exception*?

Comment: @cricket_007 , it returns `null` . I mean to say the `Toast` message shows `String : `, but the expected result would have been `String : abcde` where `abcde` is what I enter in `EditText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `str=edit.getText().toString();`  inside the button1 onClick() method

Comment: Thanks a ton, @cricket_007, I have done as per your instructions and I have my desired result. Thank you again :)

Comment: Thanks a ton @Wadaane

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        final EditText edit=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button button1=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                str=edit.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"String : "+str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
       });

       dialog.show();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.